# Sound capture in CPP and Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, capture

I would like to capture some sound from the microphone in cpp, in order to use it in a Qt application.

So I'm looking for a multi platform library easily integrable in a Qt4 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenAL](https://ffainelli.github.io/openal-example/) is a good, cross-platform C++ library for capturing audio.

Answer (score 7):

Qt 4.6 introduces a new, low level suite of audio APIs in the [QtMultimedia](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6-snapshot/qtmultimedia.html) module.  You can use [QAudioInput](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6-snapshot/qaudioinput.html) to capture raw audio from a microphone.

At present, this API is implemented for Windows, Mac, and Linux (supporting PULSE and ALSA audio subsystems).  Support for other platforms, including Symbian in the mobile space, is currently under development.